# Prove the following for a general binary operation, $\Delta$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I would like somebody to confirm if my proof is correct or not, please.

The question below:

> Prove the following for a general binary operation $\Delta$:
>   \begin{equation}
>     \left[ \forall_{x} \exists_{y} [y \Delta y = x] \right] \implies \left[ \forall_{x} \exists_{a} \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right]\right]
> \end{equation}

My proof:

\begin{align}
    1&. \quad \forall_{x} \exists_{y} [y \Delta y = x] \tag{assume} \\
    2&. \quad x \tag{declare} \\
    3&. \quad a = c \tag{choose} \\
    4&. \quad b = c \Delta c \tag{choose} \\
    5&. \quad ( c \Delta c ) \Delta ( c \Delta c ) = x \tag{1,3,4} \\
    6&. \quad \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right] \tag{4,5} \\
    7&. \quad \exists_{a} \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right] \tag{3 $\to$ 6} \\
    8&. \quad \forall_{x} \exists_{a} \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right] \tag{2 $\to$ 7} \\
    9&. \quad \left[ \forall_{x} \exists_{y} [y \Delta y = x] \right] \implies \left[ \forall_{x} \exists_{a} \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right]\right] \tag{1 $\to$ 8}
\end{align}

An explanation of my thought process follows (line numbers correspond to that of the proof's):

1. We assume this part.
2. Because we can't continue due to the assumption's $ \forall $ we start working backwards. Thus, we start using the conclusion's $\forall_{x} \exists_{a} \exists_{b}$. With the first part being $\forall_{x}$, we declare $x$.
3. From the next $\exists_{a}$, we choose a value for $a$. Because we are working with a general set of objects as values, we assign it a specific value called $c$.
4. From the next $\exists_{b}$, we, similarly, choose a value for $b$. We choose it to be $(c \Delta c)$, because we will be using the fact that for all $x$ there exists a value $y$ such that $y \Delta y = x$.
5. Thus, the reason we choose $b$ to be $(c \Delta c)$, is because, when we substitute the values of $a$ and $b$ into $(a \Delta a) \Delta b = x$ we find that we get $(c \Delta c) \Delta (c \Delta c) = x$, which, by line $1$, we know is true.
6. From lines $4$ and $5$ we can conclude that there does indeed exist such a value $b$ for which the statement holds.
7. From lines $3$ to $6$ we can conclude similarly that there exists such a value $a$.
8. From lines $2$ to $7$ we can conclude that this works for all $x$.
9. QED

The reason I am skeptical is that I am basically using the statement in the conclusion to conclude itself. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the given implication you need to show that if the antecedent, $ \forall_{x} \exists_{y} [y \Delta y = x]\ $, is true then the consequent, $\ \forall_{x} \exists_{a} \exists_{b} \left[ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x \right]\ $, must also be true—that is, given *any* $\ x\ $ you can find $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ such that $\ (a \Delta a) \Delta b = x\ $. The *only* assumption you're allowed to make in a valid proof is that the antecedent is true—that is, given any $\ x\ $ you can find a $\ y\ $ such that $\ y \Delta y = x\ $.

You're scepticism about the validity of your proposed proof is quite justified.  You start off correctly by assuming the antecedent in step $1$, and choosing an arbitrary $\ x\ $ in step $2$.  However, having chosen an (apparently arbitrary ) $\ c\ $ for the value of $\ a\ $ in step $3$ and then $\ c\Delta c\ $ for the value of $\ b\ $ in step $4$, you have no justification for assuming, as you appear to do in step $5$, that $\ (a\ \Delta a) \Delta b = x\ $ for those chosen values of $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $.

What you need to do in step $3$ is use your assumption that the antecedent is true to pick some value of $\ y\ $ such that $\ y\Delta y = x\ $, then let $\ b=y\ $, so you have $\ b\Delta b=x\ $. But now, the antecedent also tells you that you can find another value, $\ y_1\ $, say, of $\ y\ $ such that $\ y_1\Delta y_1=b\ $, and putting $\ a=y_1\ $ gives you $\ a\Delta a=b\ $, and hence $\ (a\ \Delta a) \Delta b = x\ $.

Comment: Great stuff. It seems so obvious now.

Do you perhaps know of any reading material about this subject? I can't seem to find any... Or maybe you could just give me some keywords like what to type into Google so that I can do the searching myself, if you don't mind, please.

Unfortunately, I don't understand our professor's logic that well, and we aren't given enough problems to work out/ solutions to verify our logic.

Comment: What exactly is the subject? The exercise itself could have come from a course on any of a wide variety of subjects.  From the tags given, I'm guessing it's something like symbolic logic, predicate calculus or the like, but I'd prefer not to have to guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The subject (class we are taking) is called Abstract Mathematics (not to be confused with Abstract Algebra, apparently). The name seems vague to me as I don't find many online sources using the same name. In the document the professor has given us, he has named it "A prelude to Mathematical Reasoning". The contents are: 1. Conjunction, 2. Implication, 3. Universal Quantifiers, 4. Existential Quantifiers, 5. Binary operations. I hope this clears things up a bit :)

Comment: @Imak Seems to me like a rather odd selection of topics from propositional and predicate calculus.  I'm not very familiar with current literature on these topics at the level that's likely to be useful for you.  However, I do think you should find Roberts's [*Introduction to Mathematical Proofs*](https://www.crcpress.com/Introduction-to-Mathematical-Proofs/Roberts/p/book/9781482246872) useful.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you, Ionza. I will take a look at that.